# Snap run Spotify generating endless errors inside terminal

Tags: spotify

`Hi!` I am enjoying using elementaryOS. As an intro, since this is my first post here.

I also enjoy using Spotify. The following error is spanning like.. once every second in the terminal after executing the `snap run`. My question is about the following harmless(Spotify works seamlessly!) yet annoying err.

```
[1123/004609.016814:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(161)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed!
```

Does anybody here know what this points to, more specific?

> I'm also posting this on the Snap forums and will update the post with
>   a link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some other people are having this same issue with Google Chrome. This answer worked for one user:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473115/google-chrome-gpu-driver-issues-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [official Spotify Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client) instead of the Snap.

Answer (score 0):

While unofficial, the [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client) version of Spotify will play nicer with the elementary and work without needing to be launched from the Terminal. AIUI this version is put out by the Spotify devs themselves but not a "blessed" version that Spotify (the company) supports but a wrapper around the Debian package.